# C#, API - Multidimensional arrays

Tags: c#, api, multidimensional-array

I have an unmanaged API function and below mentioned is it's equivalent c# code...

```
Myfunction(unit handle, int index, out bool flag,out int value, out string name);
```

Here the variable index varies from 0 to 59. I am able to fetch the data individually. I mean I can pass value to the variable index from a `TextBox` and I am getting the corresponding outputs. But how to collect the values in an array fashion. Each time I don't want to give index input I simply want to display all the values in a `ListBox`... How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we start, this is not a multidimensional array. This is a simple linear array with one index.

Create a struct to hold the values for one item:

```
struct MyItem
{
    bool flag;
    int value;
    string name;
}
```

Then have a function return an array of these:

```
MyItem[] GetItems()
{
    MyItem[] result = new MyItem[ItemCount];
    // Populate result
    return result;
}
```

Alternatively you might well store the data in a generic collection like `List<MyItem>`. Fundamentally the key is to creat a structure that can contain a single item, and then operate on collections of items.

Comment: Ok understood. I have created a structure. Can you please let me understand how to call this into my function. Am not getting the result as I did some mistake. I have written like this listBox1.items.add(getitems());

Comment: You are going to have to write bespoke code to populate the list box. It's not going to understand your struct.